# How Android WebView copy selected text to clipboard?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I'm aware there are questions asking about how to get selected text from WebView, and so far the answer seems that there's no API provided. So I'm curious to know how android.webkit.WebView accomplishes this goal. I downloaded Android Open Source Project source code but I don't really know how to navigate the codebase. Could anyone familiar with how WebView works point me to how WebView interacts with the Android system clipboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [solution](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection) about your question . This has been tested from 2.2 to 4.0.3. If your SDK is Android 4.4 , you can use  `window.getSelection()`